# Dev-C++ compile errors

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I want to use "Dev-C++" for compile c++ codes.
So I download and install it, and write this code:

```
#include <iostream.h>

main () {
     cout << "124";
}
```

but when I compiled it, it said:

> In file included from
>   E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,
>                    from [myfile path]\Untitled1.cpp:1:
>   E:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2:
>   warning: #warning This file includes
>   at least one deprecated or antiquated
>   header. Please consider using one of
>   the 32 headers found in section
>   17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the  header
>   for the  header for C++ includes,
>   or  instead of the
>   deprecated header . To
>   disable this warning use
>   -Wno-deprecated.

After I saw errors, I change my code to this code:

```
#include <iostream>

main () {
     cout << "124";
}
```

but it said again that errors.

I compile first code easily in Turbo C++, BUT in Dev-C++ ...

What can I do?

Comment: Dev-C++ is very old. Also, the compiler you are using isn't Dev-C++, it's an old version of GCC. Dev-C++ is an IDE. You should choose a more modern compiler and a more modern compiler. Try visual studio express or code::blocks.

Comment: @the_drow: A more modern compiler **and** a more modern compiler? :P

Comment: @the_drow: Those problems should happen with any compiler more modern than Turbo C++.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: LOL A more modern compiler and a more modern IDE

Comment: @UncleBens: I am aware of that, but first of all the OP isn't aware of the differences between an IDE and a Compiler, so I had to clarify that. Second of all, he is using a very outdated compiler which might not conform to the current standard of C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you write out the full definition of `main`, including the `int` return type. Leaving out the return type is an old, antiquated practice which doesn't fly these days.

Second, in the new-style headers—the ones missing the `.h` extension—the standard library is under the `std` namespace. There are two ways to make your program work:

**1.** Add an `std::` qualifier to `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::cout << "124";
}
```

**2.** Add a `using` declaration to allow unqualified references to the `std` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "124";
}
```

Comment: Please, *please* don't use option 2. If I have another person come to me complaining that they defined a function called `copy` and now they're getting all sorts of errors..... (first thing I ask is `<algorithm>` included and do you have `using namespace std;`? Well there you go!)

Comment: I prefer to do using std::count; typing 'std::' everytime is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you put `int` in front of `main () {`

I believe any C/C++ program's `main()` function is required by POSIX and the appropriate language standards to return an `int` (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

EDIT: Also, be sure to include `using namespace std;` above `int main ()`.

Comment: I don't see what POSIX has to do with DevC++ (And by extension MinGW), which don't run in a POSIX environment. (The point of requiring `int main` is right though). +1